# How to upload image and post JSON to RESTful web service in Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am trying to post a JSON entity and an image to my web service. However I don't manage to get it working. Last error is that  the request is not a multipart request.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity savePerson(@RequestPart("data") final PersonResource personResource, @RequestPart("image") MultipartFile imageFile) { ... }
```

CURL

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -F 'data={"name":"Tes
t"}' -F "image=@C:\Users\LuckyLuke\Downloads\test.jpg;type=image/jpg" localhost:8080/myapp/persons
```

Have I misunderstood the usage of `@RequestPart` annotation? Is the request wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you are using @RequestMapping in a proper way. My guess is that you are geting error since you are enforcing application/json content type (-H "Content-Type: application/json"). Try to run your program without that header (-F option should take care of setting multipart/form-data request).